# Обработчик shift и shift + del

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Стоит задача реализовать очистку listbox на нажатие <kbd>Shift</kbd> и очистку textbox на нажатие комбинации клавиш <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>. Как не писал обработчики всегда так происходит что срабатывает <kbd>Shift</kbd> но не обрабатывается <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("del");
    }
    else if (e.Shift)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("shift");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы можно было различить разницу между <kbd>Shift</kbd> и комбинацией <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>, нам нужно захватить события KeyDown и KeyUp и использовать информацию, полученную от каждого из них.

```
private Keys LastKeysDown; 
private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    LastKeysDown = e.KeyData;
}
```

В событии KeyUp мы смотрим, какие клавиши были отпущены относительно того, что было нажато в последний раз.

```
private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (LastKeysDown == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Delete) && e.KeyData == LastKeysDown)
        textBox1.Clear();

    else if (LastKeysDown == (Keys.Shift | Keys.ShiftKey) && e.KeyData == Keys.ShiftKey)
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

    LastKeysDown = Keys.None;
}
```

Comment: неплохо, но отпускать нажатую клавишу нужно не так. А только в том случае, если отжатая клавиша ровняется сохраненной зажатой. А сейчас она отжимается после отжатия любой клавиши в принципе.